# why does background process keep running in bash after exit from ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, ubuntu-18.04

This is the opposite question to the one typically asked on this subject!

Why do my background processes always keep reliably running in the background after exiting from bash/ssh when I use this recipe (without me having to use nohup, tmux, etc.)?

```
### login to ssh and run a background process, then exit
> ssh me@myserver
me@myserver> python long_running_script.py &
[1] 123456
me@myserver> exit
logout
Connection to myserver closed.

### log back in and process is still running
> ssh me@myserver
me@myserver> ps -aux | grep long_running_script
me  123456  22  0.2 71501234 1234152 ?  R1   22:22  22:36 python long_running_script.py
```

Note: this is what I want to happen, so I'm not looking for a fix. I'd just like to know why this has always worked for me on linux, when conventional wisdom is that background processes exit after logging out from ssh.

Note: this does not seem to depend on the script. I get the same behavior with shell scripts and linux commands. For example same thing happens if I run `sleep 1000 &`

Comment: "If the `huponexit` shell option has been set with shopt (see The Shopt Builtin), Bash sends a SIGHUP to all jobs when an interactive login shell exits." This is from the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html). Maybe you turned that option off?

Comment: Well another sensible explanation is  that the server you are connecting to might have specific settings or configurations that prevent background processes from being terminated on SSH logout. But I don't think that is normal.. Based on the options you excluded already, for me, no ideas come to mind.

Comment: Why do you expect it should stop running?

Comment: @dimich I thought it's the default. I didn't actually try it out on a remote server, but this post suggest the same: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-processes-running-after-ssh-session-disconnects

Comment: It's also possible the script is doing something to ignore HUP signals. Try a simple test script like `import time`; `while True: time.sleep(10)` and see if that also persists after the ssh session is closed.

Comment: I ran a different background process using linux sleep that does not depend on python and it still works.

Comment: See [When did bash's shopt huponexit start defaulting to off?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/284470/264812).

Comment: @pjh you win! Yes it looks like huponexit=off by default!

Comment: In `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, set `KillUserProcesses=yes`. I sometimes even set `KillExcludeUsers=`, which removes the `root`’s special privilege.